# Let $f \in C(\mathbb{R})$ and $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ open. Prove that $f^{−1}(A) := \{x \in \mathbb{R}:f(x) \in A\}$ is open.

Tags: analysis

Let $f$ be continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and $A$, a subset of the reals, be open. Prove that $f^{-1}(A) := \{x \in \mathbb{R}:f(x) \in A\}$ is open.

Comment: You might want to specify what definition of "continuous" you're using here (I'd assume the $\epsilon - \delta$ defition), since it's often defined as "the inverse image of every open set is open".

Comment: it is the epsilon - delta definition, yes

Answer (score 4):

Recall the definition of continuity:

**DEF** A function $f:A\to \Bbb R$ is continuous at $a\in A$ if for every $\epsilon >0$ there exists a $\delta >0$ such that $$|x-a|<\delta\implies |f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$$

Put this in terms of open balls:

**DEF** A function $f:A\to \Bbb R$ is continuous at $a\in A$ if for every ball $B(f(a);\epsilon)$ there exists a ball $B(a;\delta)$ such that $$x\in B(a;\delta)\implies f(x)\in B(f(a);\epsilon)$$

But since $f(x)\in B(f(a);\epsilon)$ means the same as $x\in f^{-1}(B(f(a);\epsilon))$ we can phrase our definition as

**DEF** A function $f:A\to \Bbb R$ is continuous at $a\in A$ if for every ball $B(f(a);\epsilon)$ there exists a ball $B(a;\delta)$ such that $$B(a;\delta)\subseteq f^{-1}(B(f(a);\epsilon))$$

---

Now we're ready to prove what you claim, plus it's converse.

**THM** A function $f:S\subseteq \Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ is continuous if and only if for every open set $A\in \Bbb R$, $f^{-1}(A)$ is open.

**PROOF** Suppose first that $f$ is continuous, and pick an open set $A$. We want to prove that $f^{-1}(A)$ is open, that is, for every $x\in f^{-1}(A)$ there exists an open ball $B(x;\delta)\subseteq f^{-1}(A)$. Pick $y\in A$. We can assume $y=f(x)$ for some $x\in f^{-1}(A)$. Since $A$ is open, there exists an open ball $B(f(x);\epsilon)\subseteq A$. Using continuity, can you show there exists an open ball $B(x;\delta)\subseteq f^{-1}(A)$?

Conversely, suppose that for every open $A$, $f^{-1}(A)$ is open. In particular, for every open ball $B(f(x),\epsilon)$, $f^{-1}(B(f(x),\epsilon))$ is open, so it contains an open ball for each of its points. What does this tell you about the continuity of$f$?

Comment: This has a lot of detail. I worry too much for a homework question without a lot of work shown.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a$ is a point of $f^{-1}(A)$. By def. of $f^{-1}(A)$, $f(a)$ is an element of $A$. Since $A$ is open, there exists $r>0$ such that $B(f(a),r)\subset A$. Because $f$ is continous, there exists $\delta>0$ such that
$$|x-a|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(a)|<r$$
for all $x$.

If you show that $B(a,\delta)\subset f^{-1}(A)$, then proof is completed, and it is easy to prove.

Comment: i don't really understand why you are doing this and how to prove that? sorry

Comment: @HELP If $A$ is subset of $\mathbb{R}$, we call $A$ is open iff for all $x\in A$ there exists $r>0$ such that $B(a,r)\subset A$. So in order to prove that $A$ is open, we find appropriate $\delta$ such that $B(a,\delta)\subset A$ for given $a\in A$. And we use $\epsilon-\delta$ definition on continuity to find these $\delta$.